# React.js, ReactTransitionGroup and refs

Tags: javascript, animation, reactjs, wrapper

I have issue with react.js and add-on ReactTransitionGroup. I am unable to keep refs of components inside ReactTransitionGroup, the add-on clones all children and sets new ref value. In my component this.refs object always stays empty because of this.

Is there any way to keep references of nodes inside the add-on?

If I wrap each child in other element like  then I have all my refs but componentWillLeave() and other animation handlers are never triggered by ReactTransitionGroup, which makes sense as hanlders don't exists on wrappers.

I am looking for any suggestions how to play around this issue. Thank you in advance.

Example here: http://www.webpackbin.com/Nk0KeN_5W

React version - 15.3

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem, I tried to reproduce it here ->
http://www.webpackbin.com/NJJ4b1OcZ
Could you edit it according to your scenario?

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I have updated code, it should be much clearer what I am talking about.

Comment: You get a new url when saving the project (original stay the same). Could you please provide url with the update?

Comment: Woops, here you go - http://www.webpackbin.com/4k6Dskd5-

Comment: how about wrapping content ? http://www.webpackbin.com/VyOqwWd9b

Comment: It solves ref problem, but creates other issue. componentWillAppear never gets called because we wrap it in to <div>. Updated example - http://www.webpackbin.com/Nk0KeN_5W